# SQL Server copy full table definition

Tags: sql-server, create-table

In the Enterprise version of SQL Server it is possible to generate the create statement for a pre-existing table by using 'Script Table as', "Create to". This generates the full create statement for the table including indices. Is there any way to do this in T-SQL and therefore be able to copy a table definition to a new table?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing simply available out of the box in straight T-SQL which exactly replicates what SSMS does.

However, you can get to this through the metadata (`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` etc), and I have done this fairly successfully.  Note that the indexes are not in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` - they are in sys.indexes.

Have a look at [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20091031132636/https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=431) which probably has most of what you want.

Comment: The formatting of the stored procedure from that article is better here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42653/A-NET-Windows-Application-To-Generate-SQL-Server-S

Answer (score 1):

Create the script to a new query window, then modify the database name and run it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really what I need to do is as described, but without using the UI in management studio. I need to do it in some T-SQL code which is being called by an SSIS package

Comment: Note: This will not get you the indexes. Those need to be scripted separately.