# how to create a duplicate table with no data in it

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

how to create a duplicate table with no data in it

old tablename--student

newtablename--student1

plz tell me the exat query

thanks,
Churchill..

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616707/sql-server-copy-full-table-definition

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT TOP 0 * INTO student1 FROM student
```

Comment: The downside is that it does not copy the indexes, PK, FK, etc. Here is how to copy the complete table structure : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18059/copy-complete-structure-of-a-table

Answer (score 2):

```
select * into student1 from student where 1=0
```

Comment: but `student1` will not contain indexes, constraints and other stuff which is part of the `student` table schema.

Answer (score 2):

First you can copy the whole table by:

```
select * into (your_table_name) from student
```

After copying the whole table, you delete the data by running:

```
truncate table (your_table_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
create table student1 as select * from student;
```

In the above query student1 is the table which has the exact copy of the already existing table student which copies the entire data.

```
create table student1 as select * from student where 0=1;
```

The query copies only the columns present in the student table but no data will be copied

But please note, you can't copy the constraints and indexes

Comment: I am getting `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.` management studio sql server for first query

Answer (score 1):

select *
  into student1
  from student
  where 1=2

This will get you the columns, 
but indexes and other objects 
will require scripting 
with a database tool of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table newtable as select * from oldtable where clause
```

Comment: this doesn't help the op...it copies data, also it doesn't copy attributes like auto increment

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server you can right click on the table name in the Object Explorer.

Select "Script Table as" > "CREATE To" and then select "New Query Editor Window"
This creates a query to create the table.
In this case table name [student] change this to [student1] in the query and run and you have an exact copy of the schema, indexes, vartypes, primary keys etc.